# List Collection in C# - adding values from command prompt

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn a little more about the List Collection and am able to get it to function when the values are added statically. List.Add(value1), but when I make it a string and try to accept data in an undefined arrary, I run into trouble and am not sure which steps to take to fix it. Can someone shed light?

Below is my Code. Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            List<string> listS = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
            listS.Add(listS) = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
            list.Add(Console.ReadLine()); // HERE !!
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked and I was able to loop through it no problem

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for...  You want to pass the string that you want to add to the collection as the parameter to the Add function.

Cheers.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        list.Add(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
lists.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

Right now, you're trying to add the list to itself...

Comment: actually, right now he's trying to add a new list he creates to the new list, which will get recreated every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
list.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
listS.Add(listS) = Console.ReadLine();
```

with:

```
listS.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

how does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
listS.Add(listS) = Console.ReadLine();
```

With

```
listS.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score -1):

When using Console.ReadLine it returns a string.

Changing your code to

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
    string listS = Console.ReadLine();
    //avoid problems with empty or nullstrings
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(listS))
    {
      list.Add(listS);
    }
}
```

would add your input to the list.

If you want to add multiple arguments through console you need to parse the string, though

Comment: Your answer is just plain BS. Please fix or delete it.

Comment: jep, fixed. meh, should have watched more closely on his code.